# Выводятся все ответы всех условий IF одновременно

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте. Есть форма в которой расположен `select`:

```
<html><body>
<form action = "8lab_1.php" method = "POST">
    <select name="myselect">
        <option value="0">Футбол</option>
        <option value="1">Теннис</option>
        <option value="2">Бокс</option>
    </select>

<input type = "submit"  value = "Продолжить">
</form>
</body></html>
```

И вторая форма, которая в зависимости от выбранного спорта выводит продаваемый на него товар:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
$sel = isset($_POST['myselect']) ? $_POST['myselect'] : '';
if($sel === '0') {$num=$sel; echo "Выбранный спорт: Футбол"; }
?>
<div id = "F">
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH1"   VALUE="1"> Мяч<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH2"  VALUE="2"> Шорты<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH3"  VALUE="3"> Футболка<BR>
</div>
<?php
$sel = isset($_POST['myselect']) ? $_POST['myselect'] : '';
if($sel === '1') {$num=$sel; echo "Выбранный спорт: Теннис";}
?>
<div id = "T">
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH4"  VALUE="1"> Ракетка<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH5"  VALUE="2"> Кроссовки<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH6"  VALUE="3"> Теннисный мяч<BR>
</div>

<?php
$sel = isset($_POST['myselect']) ? $_POST['myselect'] : '';
if($sel === '2') {$num=$sel; echo "Выбранный спорт: Бокс";}
?>
<div id = "B">
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH7"  VALUE="1"> Перчатки<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH8"  VALUE="2"> Капа<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH9"  VALUE="3"> Бинты<BR>
</div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Но в данном коде, какой товар я бы не выбрал, всё равно выводятся все `div`'ы. Подскажите, как в зависимости от выбранного товара выводить определённые чекбоксы?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> всё равно выводятся все div'ы

Ты ведь и не прячешь их никак. Перемести div-блоки внутрь фигурных скобок соответствующих им операторов if:

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<?php
$sel = isset($_POST['myselect']) ? $_POST['myselect'] : '';

if($sel === '0') :
  $num=$sel; echo "Выбранный спорт: Футбол";
?>
<div id = "F">
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH1"   VALUE="1"> Мяч<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH2"  VALUE="2"> Шорты<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH3"  VALUE="3"> Футболка<BR>
</div>
<?php
endif;

if($sel === '1') :
  $num=$sel; echo "Выбранный спорт: Теннис";
?>
<div id = "T">
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH4"  VALUE="1"> Ракетка<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH5"  VALUE="2"> Кроссовки<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH6"  VALUE="3"> Теннисный мяч<BR>
</div>
<?php
endif;

if($sel === '2') :
  $num=$sel; echo "Выбранный спорт: Бокс";
?>
<div id = "B">
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH7"  VALUE="1"> Перчатки<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH8"  VALUE="2"> Капа<BR>
<INPUT  TYPE="CHECKBOX" id="CH9"  VALUE="3"> Бинты<BR>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Работает